# select only one node and move on php

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I have a list of songs from Echonest API with Spotify URI but it adds many more songs then I need. I only need one of them not all of them but I want to keep on doing this 20 times. So I only want to get the first track inside the node and move on to the next.

[Here is the xml file I get the info from](http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/playlist/static?api_key=FILDTEOIK2HBORODV&artist=Rihanna&format=xml&results=20&type=artist&bucket=id%3aspotify-WW&bucket=tracks&limit=true)

This is the PHP I use:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:Playlist based on Rihanna:<?php 
$completeurl = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/playlist/static?api_key=FILDTEOIK2HBORODV&artist=Rihanna&format=xml&results=20&type=artist-radio&bucket=tracks&bucket=id:spotify-WW"; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl); 
$i = 1;
foreach ($xml->xpath('//songs') as $playlist) {
    $spotify_playlist = $playlist->foreign_id;
    $spotify_playlist2 = str_replace("spotify-WW:track:",'',$spotify_playlist);
    echo  "$spotify_playlist2,"; 
    if ($i++ == 10) break;
}
?>" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="float: right"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean without reviewing the XML or seeing your output. Please update your question.

Comment: Two specific points to clarify: a) "I only want to get the first track inside the node and move on to the next" the first track inside which node (`<song>`?) and the next what (playlist?)? b) Your code loops over `<songs>` elements, but your example only contains one, and it doesn't have a `<foreign_id>` node under it; does this code actually work?

Answer (score 0):

> So I only want to get the first track inside the node and move on to the next.

You are describing [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) - which moves to the next iteration and skips the following code in the current loop. Whereas `break` ends the current loop.

Comment: But the number chance depending of how many results it gets so I can never know how many it should jump over.. How can I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the number of songs by counting the result:

```
$numberOfSongsElements = count($xml->xpath('//songs'));
```

This should allow to find out if the song you want to retrieve is in there. For example:

```
$playlistNumber = 1;
if ($playlistNumber > $numberOfSongsElements) {
    throw new Exception('Not enough <songs> elements');
}
$songsElement = $xml->xpath("//songs[$playlistNumber]");
```

By using the position number inside the Xpath predicate:

```
//songs[1]  --  abbreviated form of: //songs[position()=1]
//songs[2]
//songs[3]
...
```

You can directly select the node you're interested in, be it first (`1`) or some other number or even last (`last()`). See [2.4 Predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) and [4.1 Node Set Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Node-Set-Functions).

Hope this is helpful. As already commented, your question was not that clear. I hope the counting and numbered access will allow you to select the element you're looking for at least programmatically.